# Mitigating the Runge Phenomenon with Constrained Norm Minimization

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, approximation-theory

I am interested in polynomial interpolation of a set of points in $\{(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

On the wikipedia page for Runge's phenomenon, the [Constrained Minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon#Constrained_minimization) section informs me that a route for avoiding the Runge phenomenon is to fit a degree $p$ polynomial with $p >> n$ such that it is of minimum "wigglyness" but still interpolates the data.

Unfortunately, this section has no inline citations, and googling "runge phenomenon constrained minimization" did not yield relevant results.

Is there a common name for this technique that will help me to find literature describing it? Can anyone recommend any such literature?

Comment: Please read "A practical guide to splines" by Carl DeBoor.

Comment: @szw1710 I'll have a look, thank you for the suggestion